# I want to get the total callback count from the below texts corresponding to the Device Id

Tags: powershell

Here is the text:

```
"2021-03-08 07:06:31.4268 DEBUG  [35]  Method:Itron.Ami.Reachability.ReachabilityManager.ProcessDeviceReachabilityCallback (391)  -- [NotificationReport: REACHABLE_FOR_DATA, Status: Success, DeviceIds: 011629700000075, MonitorId: 1F1FF1F1-71A1-71A2-0000-0000042C1D87, ReportTime: 3/8/2021 12:06:31 PM, CallbackCount: 1, CallbackTimespanSeconds: .43]"
```

I have been asked, to pass the `DeviceId` from the PowerShell window as a value and have to write Powershell function which will accept the `DeviceId` as a parameter and corresponding to that `DeviceId` I have to print `CallbackCount` on the PowerShell window as result.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you have tried sofar. Note this is *not* a script factory. You will need to write the script yourself. If you run into a problem that isn't yet covered by the existing questions and answers, you might post your [mcve] here so that we might be able to help you further. See also: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use regex

```
$log = @"
2021-03-08 07:06:31.4268 DEBUG  [35]  Method:Itron.Ami.Reachability.ReachabilityManager.ProcessDeviceReachabilityCallback (391)  -- [NotificationReport: REACHABLE_FOR_DATA, Status: Success, DeviceIds: 011629700000075, MonitorId: 1F1FF1F1-71A1-71A2-0000-0000042C1D87, ReportTime: 3/8/2021 12:06:31 PM, CallbackCount: 1, CallbackTimespanSeconds: .43]
2021-03-08 07:06:31.4268 DEBUG  [35]  Method:Itron.Ami.Reachability.ReachabilityManager.ProcessDeviceReachabilityCallback (391)  -- [NotificationReport: REACHABLE_FOR_DATA, Status: Success, DeviceIds: 011629700000076, MonitorId: 1F1FF1F1-71A1-71A2-0000-0000042C1D87, ReportTime: 3/8/2021 12:06:31 PM, CallbackCount: 3, CallbackTimespanSeconds: .43]
"@

function Get-CallbackCount {
    param (
        $DeviceId,
        [string[]]$Log
    )
    $regexPattern = "DeviceIds:\s(\w+${DeviceId}).+CallbackCount:\s(\d+),"

    foreach ($line in $log) {
        If ($line -match $regexPattern) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                DeviceId      = $Matches[1]
                CallbackCount = $Matches[2]
            }
        }
    }
}

Get-CallbackCount -DeviceId '11629700000076' -Log $log
Get-CallbackCount -DeviceId '00000075' -Log $log
```

Output

```
DeviceId        CallbackCount
--------        -------------
011629700000076 3
011629700000075 1
```